# Hibernate setup for one-to-many/many-to-one relationship

Tags: hibernate

I am a little confused about the proper choice of the owning side of a one-to many/many-to-one relationship when using Hibernate.
I can imagine two examples of this kind of relationship:

1. The pair Order/OrderLine is a first example. In this pair Order has the 'master' role. One would like to save order, saving all of the items as a consequence.
2. The pair Group/User is a second example. In this pair User has the 'master' role. One would prefer to save the user by assigning him to a certain group.

The internal structure of both examples is the same if we abstract away from the details, like in

```
public class Order/Group implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Set<OrderLine/User> children = new HashSet<OrderLine/User>();
}

public class OrderLine/User implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Order/Group parent;
}
```

The hibernate annotation mapping will be respectively

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
```

logically leaving OrderLine/User the owning side.

Do the abovementioned use cases exert any influence on the choice of the relationship owning side? Shall one inverse the owning side or saving/deleting parent with cascading options will suffice? Is it normal to add/delete some children and then persist parent to the database with `orphanRemoval` (order - order line) or without it (group - user)? In the end, which side shall be responsible for certain actions, like in clearing a group user stays currently in, or changing the order by adding and removing items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have much choice. In a bidirectional OneToMany association, the owner side is always the Many side (Hibernate has some trick to make the inverse possible, but it's horrible, and not supported by JPA, AFAIK).

But don't attribute too much value to this ownership. The only thing it means is that Hibernate will only consider the `parent` field in OrderLine (or User) to determine if an association exists. That's all. You're still free to organize your code as you will, provided that you remember to initialize the parent field if you want to add an OrderLine to an Order, and to set it to null if you want to detach it from its Order.

Comment: So in this case if I want to manage the objects by the owned side, I will set up the proper parent field in all of the children I would like to save/update, set the parent field to null in all of the children I would like to remove, rearrange the list/set of children in parent accordingly and will save the parent, I can be sure that this will be a good programming practice that won't create unnecessary stuff, right?

Comment: I suppose, yes. Hard to tell without a specific use-case and code. If you work with attached entities, you don't need to save anything. Just modify the state of the entities, and the changes will be persisted automatically.